# How to using stream in java 8 filter two list object and set value to new List

Tags: java, foreach, collections, java-8, java-stream

I using java 8 and i have two object look like :

Person class :

```
public class Person {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Person1 Class :

```
public class Person1 {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public Person1() {
    }

    public Person1(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person1{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I have two list look like :

```
 List<Person> persons= Arrays.asList(new Person("1","A"),new Person("2","B"));
  List<Person1> persons1 = Arrays.asList(new Person1("3","C"),new Person1("1","F"));
```

Now i want using stream java 8 loop two list and compare. If any object in list persons equal with persons1 , i will create new list and set it with new value. Example : **If Person1("1","F") equal Person("1","A")** because i using **id** compare it, i get name from Person1 set to Person. Result : Person("1,"F") and add it two new list.

My code when i using for:

```
 for (Person person : persons) {
            for (Person1 person1 : persons1 ) {
                if (person1.getId().equals(person.getId())) {
                    person.setName(person1.getId());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Now i want convert it to Stream with new list look like :

```
 List<Person> personList =
                list.stream()
                        .filter (
                                person -> list1.stream()
                                        .anyMatch(person1 -> person1.getId()== person.getId()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But it only filter person. I want compare two list object. If same id, i want set name from object in persons1  to persons. I know we can using map in stream java 8 but i can't how to do that. Please help

Comment: Why you want to use a break; here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some tasks are best accomplished with streams, and others with iteration. Many tasks are best accomplished by combining the two approaches. In this solution streams are used to construct the map and then iteration is used to update matching person's name. Your solution runs in Quadratic time whereas this solution runs in linear time complexity.

```
Map<String, String> idToNameMap = persons1.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person1::getId, Person1::getName, (a, b) -> a));
for (Person person : persons) {
    if (idToNameMap.containsKey(person.getId())) {
        person.setName(idToNameMap.get(person.getId()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `idToNameMap.get(p.getId()) != null`, you can use `idToNameMap.containsKey(p.getId())`. But constructing new `Person` instances is not the same as modifying existing objects.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the answer. Also I did not update the existing object since it contradicts with immutability in functional programming.

Comment: Well, that contradiction is inherent  to the task. If you assume immutable objects, there wouldn’t be a need to construct new objects either, as the objects in `persons1` do already have the desired properties and only need to be filtered.

Comment: I have updated the answer using a hybrid approach. Thanks a lot for the feedback.

Comment: Thanks you very much. But i have a question : why we need param:  (a, b) -> a
Because when i try code :

  Map<String, String> idToNameMap = persons.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person1::getId, Person1::getName));
        persons
                .stream()
                .filter(item -> idToNameMap.containsKey(item.getId()))
                .forEach(item -> item.setName(idToNameMap.get(item.getId())));

        person.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

It same result with you. Can you explain me a thing about it

Comment: If there are key conflicts, it will use that merge function to handle it. But in your case since there are not key conflicts, it works.

Comment: Thanks you . I have a question. I can create new List and add result after stream to it ? Right ? I mean new list contain only result after caculate not all element from persons

Comment: I didn't get your question?

Comment: Oh my question answer bellow. Thanks you

Comment: A fully stream based solution would be something like this `List<Person> updatedPersons = persons.stream()
 .map(p -> idToNameMap.containsKey(p.getId()) ? new Person(p.getId(), idToNameMap.get(p.getId())) : p)
 .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1):

It's not the most beautiful answer etc but i guess it's gonna help u get idea how its work.

```
List<Person> collect = persons.stream()
        .filter(person -> persons1.stream().anyMatch(person1 -> person1.getId() == person.getId()))
        .map(person -> {
            Person1 getted = persons1.stream()
                .filter(person1 -> person1.getId() == person.getId())
                .findAny()
                .orElseGet(null);
            if (getted == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Should be Impossible");
            person.setName(getted.getName());
            return person;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```